# Passing Javascript variable to <a href >

Tags: javascript

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
var scrt_var = 10; 
</script>
```

HTML Part:

```
<html>
 this is a <a href ="2.html & Key= scrt_var">Link  </a>
</html>
```

I just want to sent the javascript variable to link (url parameter)

No AJAX

Comment: please frame your question properly so that you can get maximum out of it

Answer (score 65, accepted):

If you want it to be dynamic, so that the value of the variable at the time of the click is used, do the following:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
var scrt_var = 10; 
</script>
<a href="2.html" onclick="location.href=this.href+'?key='+scrt_var;return false;">Link</a>
```

Of course, that's the quick and dirty solution. You should really have a script that after DOM load adds an onclick handler to all relevant `<a>` elements.

Comment: i can't use that variable but I can see it in the addressbar. How can I use it?

Comment: Hi. Can i use instead of variable a function which returns string?

Comment: This doesn't do anything.

Comment: This is horrible advice; don't use JavaScript to do what an anchor does naturally; just change the `href` attribute of the anchor to the URL you want.

Comment: While this answer is 11 years old and things would normally be done a bit differently today, I don't think it's fair to say it's horrible advice. For example, if you had 1,000 anchors on the page and each one depended on a variable, would you really suggest to change 1,000 `href` attributes every time the variable changes? As always, context matters and people's advice are rarely objectively "horrible".

Answer (score 28):

put id attribute on anchor element

```
<a id="link2">
```

set href attribute on page load event:

```
(function() {
    var scrt_var = 10;
    var strLink = "2.html&Key=" + scrt_var;
    document.getElementById("link2").setAttribute("href",strLink);
})();
```

Answer (score 14):

Alternatively you could just use a document.write:

```html
<script type="text\javascript">
var loc = "http://";
document.write('<a href="' + loc + '">Link text</a>');
</script>
```

Comment: [Why is document.write considered a "bad practice"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/802854) (it was considered bad practice back in '09 too).

Answer (score 13):

```
<script>
   var scrt_var = 10;
   document.getElementById("link").setAttribute("href",scrt_var);
</script>
<a id="link">this is a link</a>
```

Comment: I think that it would be something like setAttribute("href", "2.html & Key=" + scrt_var) to form the complete link.

Comment: Yeah that thing works, Thanks for the short & simple trick :) @erenon

Comment: @erenon Is there a way to add target_new to this code to open in a new tab? thank you.

Comment: @Andrew: .setAttribute("target", "new") chained after the previous similar call. However, please note pop up windows are rather disliked.

Comment: Thanks! That worked. Opening in a new tab is considered a popup window?I agree I dislike advertisement popup windows that show up in a new browser window, but I find it easier to compare two pages or go back to a page when both are in different tabs.

Comment: @Andrew If you omit `target=_new`, the user can control click or right click to open a new window or tab.  If you use `target=_new`, the user can't avoid opening a new window or tab.  It's better to give the user the option instead of forcing them to do it the way you want.

Answer (score 9):

```
<html>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
var scrt_var = 10; 
openPage = function() {
location.href = "2.html?Key="+scrt_var;
}
</script>

 this is a <a href ="javascript:openPage()">Link  </a>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use an express framework

```node
app.get("/:id",function(req,res)
{
  var id = req.params.id;
  res.render("home.ejs",{identity : id});
});
```

Express file, which receives a JS variable identity from node.js

`<a href = "/any_route/<%=identity%>` includes identity JS variable into your `href` without a trouble enter

Comment: Check your answer code. I am fixed the code but something missing there anyway.

Comment: The question shows the variable is in client-side JS. They can't use Express there.

Answer (score -1):

If you use internationalization (i18n), and after switch to another language, something like `?locale=fr`or `?fr` might be added at the end of the url. But when you go to another page on click event, translation switch wont be stable.

For this kind of cases a DOM click event handler function must be produced to handle all the `a.href` attributes by storing the switch state as a variable and add it to all `a` tags’ tail.

Answer (score -1):

JAVASCRIPT CODE:

```
<script>

    function getUrlVars()
{
    var vars = [], hash;
    var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
    for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++)
    {
        hash = hashes[i].split('=');
        vars.push(hash[0]);
        vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
    }
    return vars;
}

var user = getUrlVars()["user"];
var pass = getUrlVars()["pass"];
var sub  = getUrlVars()["sub"];
</script>

<script>
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('dropdownCtrl', ['$scope','$window','$http', function($scope, $window, $http) {

 $http.get('http://dummy.com/app/chapter.php?user='+user+'&pass='+pass)

     .then(function (response) {$scope.names = response.data.admin;});
    $scope.names = [];

        $http.get('http://dummy.com/app/chapter.php?user='+user+'&pass='+pass+'&sub='+sub)

            .then(function (response) {$scope.chapter = response.data.chp;});
           $scope.chapter = [];

};


}]);
    </script>
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="dropdownCtrl">
<div ng-repeat="a in chapter">
<a href="topic.html?ch={{a.chapter}}" onClick="location.href=this.href+'&user='+user+'&pass='+pass+'&sub='+sub;return false;">{{a.chapter}}</a>
</div>
```

Comment: This seems to be an excessively complicated approach … and one which has at least one external dependency that you haven't explained how to load.