# How to Customize Hyperlinks on Client Side in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I need to be able to do two things with Javascript or JQuery, without involving third-party open source libraries:

1. Use a jQuery or Javascript function to fill the HREF attribute of a link.
2. Perform an HTTP Get or Post operation OnUpdate of a text box or combo box (using the above javascript function to specify the HTTP target)

The end result will be hyperlinks posted to the controller that look similar to this:

```
http://mydomain/addresses/1?order=name&state=ca
```

The controller will return a new page, ordered by name and filtered on the state of California.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have 2 textboxes and a hyperlink with url, try something like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a#yourHyperLinkId').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var url = $(this).attr('href');
        var order = $('input#order').val();
        var state = $('input#state').val();
        $.get(url, { order: order, state: state }, function(response) {
            $('div#yourDivForResponse').html(response);
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I follow...

Why do you need to fill the HREF of the link if your going to use JQuery to do the postback anyway?

Comment: Yes it will - just create the url and either just redirect the window for a full postback, or use JQuery's Ajax calls to post back the data and update the revelant element.

It sounds like your saying that the URL will vary dependant upon the user's action? If this is not the case then render the URL directly on the server side.

Answer (score 1):

1. Some elements of answer here : [Passing Javascript variable to <a href >](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/975050/passing-javascript-variable-to-a-href)
2. If you want to load the controller response in the window, you can use a form with a crafted *action*. If not, you can either use an iframe as a *target* to the form or use an XHR object. Whatever solution you choose, you will link it to the onchange event of the text box or combo box.

Comment: I like document.getElementById("link2").setAttribute("href",strLink);

Answer (score 0):

Thanks fellas for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer to #1:

```
document.getElementById("link2").setAttribute("href",strLink);
```

Answer to #2 (more or less):

```
$("#mySelect").change(function() {  
  document.location = this.value;
});
```