# How to insert a javascript variable in <a href="">

Tags: javascript, html

```
I have a javascript variable BASE_URL='http://localhost/BKTHP_WEB_NEW/';
```

Now I want to insert it inside a

```
something like <a href="BASE_URL+\view">
```

Comment: just set `href` attribute using javascript or jquery.

Comment: you can not put javascript variable into anchor tag directly you have to write script to change the href attribute dynamically.

Comment: Try this:


`<a id="myLink">

$('#myLink').attr('href', 'https://www.google.com');`

Comment: this can be helpful. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/975050/passing-javascript-variable-to-a-href

Answer (score 3):

Use `setAttribute` to set the variable as a value for href

```js
var BASE_URL='http://localhost/BKTHP_WEB_NEW/';
document.querySelector('a').setAttribute('href',BASE_URL)
```

```html
<a href="">Link
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `setAttribute` on your a tag, and set the `href` dynamically

```html
<a id="replace" href="">YOUR LINK</a>
```

```js
const BASE_URL='http://localhost/BKTHP_WEB_NEW/';
document.querySelector('#replace').setAttribute('href', BASE_URL);
```