# how to pass 2 links in single href tag

Tags: javascript, html

I have 2 html pages, movies.html and single.html.
In movies.html i have added list of movies, clicking on any movie will take us to single to html along with movie link. I have pasted the code below for better understanding.

```
<a href="single.html?movieLink=https://drive.google.com/u/0/uc?export=download&confirm=6KcH&id=1oezcBrXr8b-ATkIGD1I9ZQakPP9VX_5W">
```

Assume the movieLink given redirect to single.html and will start downloading the movie directly.
For getting the link in next page i have written a java script code.

But what I want is that I want to redirect the page to single.html, there I have given 2 options 720px and 1080px. After clicking on the resolution needed it should start to download the specific file.

which means I have to pass 2 href links from the movie.html page, how can i do that?

Comment: @Susha how much impact or change it required after selecting a resolution what will be both URLs ?

Answer (score 0):

So your URL will be

```
single.html?param1=linkone&param2=linktwo
```

and then you can use these two as functions to get the two parameters.

```
var param1 = getParameterByName('param1'); //return linkone
var param2 = getParameterByName('param2'); //return linktwo
```

Comment: <script>
  function bindUrlWithIFrame(){
   var movieLink1 = window.location.href.split("?movieLink1=")[1];
    var movieLink2 = window.location.href.split("?movieLink2=")[1];
    document.write('<a href="' + movieLink1 + '">Download 720px</a></br>');
     document.write('<a href="' + movieLink2 + '">Download 1080px</a>');
       }
      bindUrlWithIFrame();
</script>

I have written a javascript code as above to fetch both the variables. 
movieLink1 value I am getting it is not downloading the movie, movieLink2 value it says undefined.
Can you please provide me any solution.

Comment: Yeah, understood the answer but what I am asking is getParameterByName('param1') will be inside script tag in html file right.
So if i want to use the variable param1 outside the script tag how can i use. 
Like <a href= + param1 +>download</a>
I want to give the variable param1 in href outside the script tag, can you please help.

Comment: @Sushma https://stackoverflow.com/questions/975050/passing-javascript-variable-to-a-href